# Traefik with docker backend leads to bad gateway

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I set up a debian server where I installed docker and docker-compose.

I created in the home of my sudo user a folder with the following hierarchy:

```
~/docker-project
      - docker-compose.yml
      - /traefik/traefik.toml
```

I do a `docker-compose up -d` everything is started I can reach traefik.mydomain.com that has working ssl certificate as does the other subdomains. But if I go to any of my subdomain to reach my dockerized web service, I get a **bad gateway** message in my browser. If I go to my server IP adress and put the right port, I see my webservice working perfectly.

So I think I've made a mistake configuring the docker / traefik relationship but I'm unable to find where.

Here is my `traefik.toml`:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

################################################################
# Web configuration backend
################################################################
[web]
address = ":8080"
[web.auth.basic]
# User: user | Password: password
users = ["user:hashedpassword"]

################################################################
# Entry-points configuration
################################################################
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

################################################################
# Docker configuration backend
################################################################
[docker]
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

################################################################
# Let's encrypt
################################################################
[acme]
email = "my-email@mail.com"
storageFile = "/etc/traefik/acme.json"
onDemand = false
onHostRule = true
entryPoint = "https"
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

  traefik:
    restart: always
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '8080:8080'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=8080'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mydomain.com'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik:/etc/traefik

  plex:
    image: linuxserver/plex
    container_name: plex
    environment:
      - VERSION=latest
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=TZ
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=9001'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:plex.mydomain.com' 
    ports:
      - '9001:32400'
    volumes:
      - 'plex:/config'
      - 'plex_transcode:/transcode'
      - '/home/downloader/Downloads:/data/'

  plexpy:
    image: linuxserver/plexpy
    container_name: plexpy
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=TZ
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=9002'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:plexpy.mydomain.com' 
    ports:
      - '9002:8181'
    volumes:
      - 'plexpy:/config'

  transmission:
    image: linuxserver/transmission
    container_name: transmission
    environment:
      - PGID=1000
      - PUID=1000
      - TZ=TZ
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=9003'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:bt.mydomain.com' 
    ports:
      - '9003:9091'
      - '51413:51413'
      - '51413:51413/udp'
    volumes:
      - 'transmission:/config'
      - '/home/downloader/Downloads:/downloads'
      - '/home/downloader/Downloads:/watch'

volumes:
  plex:
    driver: local
  plex_transcode:
    driver: local
  plexpy:
    driver: local
  transmission:
    driver: local
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I managed to get an answer thanks to the terrific traefik slack channel!

So my containers are all in the same docker network including my traefik container.

The problem is that I mapped all my containers port to be accessible from the host machine.

Instead I should have only mapped traefik ports to the host machine and just **exposed** the ports of my web services containers so that traefik can listen to them inside the docker network where they are all in.

Change : - **add** expose
         - **change** traefik.port

I just had to do this changes in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  traefik:
    restart: always
    image: traefik
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '8080:8080'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=8080'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mydomain.com'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik:/etc/traefik

  plex:
    image: linuxserver/plex
    container_name: plex
    environment:
      - VERSION=latest
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=TZ
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=32400'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:plex.mydomain.com' 
    #ports:
    #  - '9001:32400'
    expose:
      - 32400
    volumes:
      - 'plex:/config'
      - 'plex_transcode:/transcode'
      - '/home/downloader/Downloads:/data/'

  plexpy:
    image: linuxserver/plexpy
    container_name: plexpy
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=TZ
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=8181'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:plexpy.mydomain.com' 
    #ports:
    #  - '9002:8181'
    expose:
      - 8181
    volumes:
      - 'plexpy:/config'

  transmission:
    image: linuxserver/transmission
    container_name: transmission
    environment:
      - PGID=1000
      - PUID=1000
      - TZ=TZ
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=dockerplatform_default'
      - 'traefik.port=9091'
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:bt.mydomain.com' 
    #ports:
    #  - '9003:9091'
    #  - '51413:51413'
    #  - '51413:51413/udp'
    expose:
      - 9091
      - 51413
    volumes:
      - 'transmission:/config'
      - '/home/downloader/Downloads:/downloads'
      - '/home/downloader/Downloads:/watch'

volumes:
  plex:
    driver: local
  plex_transcode:
    driver: local
  plexpy:
    driver: local
  transmission:
    driver: local
```

Comment: I was also redirecting my traffic to localhost instead of mapping it to the docker network shared by the containers. You saved me a big deal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Traefik v2 is out now, this question deserves an update:

- The `expose` port defnition isn't necessary anymore.
- Neither is a `port` mapping definition for that container.
- The only thing necessary is, that something in the container is listening.

*Note:* If you define for e.g. an Nginx container, add the label
`- 'traefik.port=9091'`
but also add a server conf that listens on port `9091`.

Comment: what do you mean by "something in the container is listening?

Comment: @MiBe something listening on a port